# Using memcached to host images

Tags: python, image, flask, memcached

Im writing simple blogging platform in Flask microframework, and I'd like to allow users to change image on the front page but without actually writing it into filesystem. Is it possible to point src attribute in img tag to an object stored in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it.

1. Create a controller or serlvet called for example
   www.yoursite.com/getImage/ID
2. When you execute this URL, your
   program shoud connect to the memcached and return the image object
   that you have previously stored in it.
3. Finally when in your html you add: src="www.yoursite.com/getImage/ID" the browser will execute
   this url, but instead of reading a file from disk it will ask the memcached for the specific ID.

Be sure to add the correct content-type in your response from the server in order that the browser understand that you are sending an image content.

Fer